# Best practice - Storage options for external reference data that is queried in different ways

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We have a cloud platform with various Health Care applications.  Each application needs what we call reference data.  Reference data is always external data coming from a provider  on a daily or some regular schedule.  An example of reference data is FDB MedKnowledge which includes a comprehensive compendium of consumer medication monographs, along with drug images and imprints.

Various applications will query the reference data to present it to their target customers (who can be physicians, nurses, technicians, procurement department etc...).  A common global API will be developed to return the requested data.

Historical information is required ( for ex:  FDB in 2017 had NDC1 which then got deleted from the FDB feed in 2019.  So a physician who prescribed NDC1 should be able to query the information of that drug going through history).

Daily we receive the feed from the external provider and use it as input source to merge ( update, insert, delete) our reference data copy such that its live table reflects the latest external feed.

In Azure, we have the following storage options:
Blob storage
Cosmos Db
Azure sql database with system versioning
Azure Datawarehouse
Azure Data lake

What is the best practice to store external reference data?  We are leaning toward azure sql database with system versioning.  Have any of you worked with external reference data?  If yes, what is your storage decision and has it worked well for you? I would like to hear your comments and opinions.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to base your choice on the type of data you are trying to store, and how you need to reference it. It sounds like you might actually need a few different technologies here.

For example, Azure SQL is great for storing relational data. So if your data is tabular in form and needs to have relationships between it, then this is a good choice. However, if you're going to be storing millions and millions of rows then performance might suffer in a relational database. In that sort of scenario, or one where you have lots of transactional data you might want to look at Cosmos DB.

You mentioned images at one point, putting these in a database is not a good idea, in this sort of scenario you are going to want to look at using blob storage.

"Reference Data" really doesn't mean anything, look at the individual types of data you need to store, and how this data is used, and make decisions based on this. For lots of different types of data, there is unlikely to be a one size fits all solution.